# Can IOS copy local file over 300MB?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, sqlite

Hello to every awesome developer in the entire world!

What I'am trying to do is copying a database file from main application bundle to the IOS document folder, the code seems fine but it always fail to copy the file, the destination file always has zero byte !
so, what went wrong is the following code!

**Swift 5**

```
    private func moveDbFile() {
        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        print(documentsDirectory)
        
        guard let sourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "database", ofType: "db") else {
            return
        }

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: sourcePath) {
            let sourceUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: sourcePath)
            let destination = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("database.db", isDirectory: false)
            try? fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceUrl, to: destination)

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
                print("file copied")
            } else {
                print("file copy failed")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you detect some error using `do`-`try`-`catch` instead of `try?` ?

Comment: There are no errors as far as i know

Comment: There should be an error thrown in the catch block once implemented. It's detailed here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1407903-copyitem

Comment: "the destination file always has zero byte" When and how are you calculating the file size?  How do you know when the app finishes calculating the file size?

Comment: @ElTomato You can check file size in many ways, the easy one is by accessing `.document` folder in IOS simulator

Comment: @P.Coder - no problem copying a large file (quick test with a 400 MB file worked fine). Is it possible you tried some other method (that didn't work properly), and you already have a "database.db" file in the docs dir? You should *at least* implement `do / try / catch` on `copyItem()` to make sure it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by add database file to project target membership

Comment: That's why you should use `do / try / catch`.